# not getting output for json .saved in pars.html format

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
  <head>
    <center>
      <h2> create object from json string</h2>
    </center>
    <script>
     var text='{"fruits":[' + '{"name":"apple","price":"1000"},'
                + '{"name":"orange","price":"2000"},'
                + '{"name":"pine","price":"3000"}]}'
     obj1=JSON.parse(text);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTml = obj1.fruits[1].name + "" + obj1.fruits[2].price;
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

I am not able to get the o/p for this concept.I am not able to understand what is parsing.

Comment: `innerHTml` or `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is case-sensitive and you are currently using `innerHTml` instead of [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), which will not work :

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = obj1.fruits[1].name + '' + obj1.fruits[2].price;
```

Additionally, you may want to simply use a single line to define your JSON string to avoid issues when building it :

```
var text = '{"fruits":[{"name":"apple","price":"1000"},{"name":"orange","price":"2000"},{"name":"pine","price":"3000"}]}'
```

**Example**

```
<body>
  <center><h2>create object from json string</h2></center>
  <pre>DEMO</pre>
  <!-- Required Demo Section -->
  <div id='demo'></div>
  <script>
     // Slightly revised building of JSON collection (to avoid concatenation issues)
     var text= '{"fruits":[{"name":"apple","price":"1000"},{"name":"orange","price":"2000"},{"name":"pine","price":"3000"}]}';
     var obj1= JSON.parse(text);
     // Use of proper innerHTML property
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj1.fruits[1].name+ ' ' + obj1.fruits[2].price;
  </script>
</body>
```

You can [see this example in action here](http://jsbin.com/caserom/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 0):

Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerHTml`

```js
  var text = '{"fruits":[' + '{"name":"apple","price":"1000"}, ' + '{"name":"orange","price":"2000"}, ' + '{"name":"pine","price":"3000"} ]  }';
  obj1 = JSON.parse(text);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj1.fruits[1].name + " " + obj1.fruits[2].price;
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <center>
    <h2> create object from json string</h2>
  </center>

  <div id="demo"></div>
</head>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Errors I could spot:

1. Forgot to add `#dome` element on your page
2. `innerHTml` should be `innerHTML`
3. `text` variable is not being correctly initialised. It's a parsing error. String closing quote and plus `'+` should be on the string closing line like in the example below.

---

```js
 var text = '{"fruits":[{"name":"apple","price":"1000"},' +
   '{"name":"orange","price":"2000"},' +
   '{"name":"pine","price":"3000"}' +
   ']}';

 obj1 = JSON.parse(text);

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = obj1.fruits[1].name + " " + obj1.fruits[1].price;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<center>
  <h2> create object from json string</h2>
</center>
<div id="demo"></demo>
```